# Upload Photo To Album with Facebook's Graph API

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to familiarize myself with Facebook's new Graph API and so far I can fetch and write some data pretty easily.

Something I'm struggling to find decent documentation on is uploading images to an album.

According to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing you need to supply the **message** argument. But I'm not quite sure how to construct it.

Older resources I've read are:

- http://wiki.auzigog.com/Facebook_Photo_Uploads
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.upload/

If someone has more information or could help me tackle uploading photos to an album using Facebook Graph API please reply!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here are some various ways to upload photos using the PHP Facebook Graph API.  The examples assume you've instantiated the $facebook object and have a valid session.

## 1 - Upload to Default Application Album of Current User

This example will upload the photo to your default application album of the current user.  If the album does not yet exist it will be created.

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$args = array('message' => 'Photo Caption');
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath($FILE_PATH);

$data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
print_r($data);
```

## 2 - Upload to Target Album

This example will upload the photo to a specific album.

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$args = array('message' => 'Photo Caption');
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath($FILE_PATH);

$data = $facebook->api('/'. $ALBUM_ID . '/photos', 'post', $args);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Don't forget to add: $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

Comment: @Abe Yes that is correct, you can also specify this in the Facebook constructor:$facebook = new Facebook(array(  
  'appId'  => 'ID',  
  'secret' => 'SECRET',  
  'fileUpload' => true,  
  'cookie' => true));

Comment: can the album ID not be my album but a friend's or a page's album?

Comment: is there any way to send `image/resource handle` instead of `realpath`?

Answer (score 23):

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
//upload photo
$file= '/path/filename.jpg';
$args = array(
   'message' => 'Photo from application',
);
$args[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath($file);
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$album_id.'/photos?access_token='.$access_token;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
//returns the photo id
print_r(json_decode($data,true));
```

Link to documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo

Comment: How do you know this? Any documentation from Facebook.com?

Comment: I'd also like to know where you found this! Unless you rolled your own?

Comment: Is this still working for you? There seem to be a problem on the FB platform lately with photo uploads

Comment: Any idea about uploading photo from javascript sdk.

Answer (score 7):

You have to do a few things to get the graph api to work with php. This code works. Notice the fileUpload => true...

I also was never able to get it to work with javascript so I'm doing ajax to this:

`require './facebook.php';`

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(  
  'appId'  => 'ID',  
  'secret' => 'SECRET',  
  'fileUpload' => true,  
  'cookie' => true // enable optional cookie support  
));  


$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);  

# File is relative to the PHP doc  
$file = "@".realpath("../../_images/stuff/greatness.jpg");  

$args = array(  
    'message' => 'Photo Caption',  
    "access_token" => "urtoken",  
    "image" => $file  
);  


$data = $facebook->api('/ALBUMID_GOES_HERE/photos', 'post', $args);
if ($data) print_r("success");
```

Comment: Thanks - that's what I forgot with the PHP SDK, to set setFileUploadSupport to true!