# How to post an image to wall of facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using C#.net and graph api.I wanted to post an image(local pc image not hosted somewhere) to my facebook page.I have created the web request for this.Iam able to create graph api web request for creating album.I wanted to post image to that album.But I am getting an error(#324 upload file).
.Here my web request for uploading image to photo.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/albumid/photos?access_token=application access token&method=post&picture=D:\\Image\\LIKES.jpg
```

Comment: This might be helpful (dealing with the same error): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211968/exception-when-uploading-photo-with-facebook-graph-api

Answer (score 0):

Select Home, there you can see Status, Photo, Link etc., Here Select Photo, then select upload a photo, make it to public to visible to all.

Comment: I am asking through code.(graph api not through facebook directly)

Comment: @pinky This is not a Generate Code forum! Show us what you already did and where're you stumble upon and we might help you.