# Upload photo to users profile from photo URL, not input file field

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo

I have been through many of the file upload examples, but have not found a method to force the photo for the user to publish.

This example shows how a user uploads the photo from their computer:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498

I would like to use this method, but replace the [file input "browse"] field with the image URL so that the user would see it displayed, and the app would post it to their profile when they click the submit button. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look on this questons.They may help you to find your answer: > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220434/php-upload-a-web-hosted-photo-to-facebook-album-via-graph-api
> > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522650/offline-upload-photo-to-facebook-with-photo-from-web-server
> > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718610/upload-photo-to-album-with-facebooks-graph-api/2728275#2728275
> > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964410/how-can-i-upload-photos-to-album-using-facebook-graph-api/3006901#3006901
> > http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-developmen

Comment: possible duplicate of [Given a URL of an image, how do I upload that image to the Facebook user's album?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8960498/given-a-url-of-an-image-how-do-i-upload-that-image-to-the-facebook-users-album)

Answer (score 1):

What you will have to do is let the user upload the photo to your server before uploading it to Facebook.  I recommend using this great plugin called [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).  It is an AJAX file uploader, you can get callbacks during the upload process and on completion.  When you receive an `uploadComplete` callback you can display the image to your user before allowing him to submit the image to Facebook. For submitting the photo to Facebook I recommend following one of the tutorials listed in the other answer by @Abdur.