# PHP Upload Image from URL to Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - Upload a web hosted photo to facebook album via Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220434/php-upload-a-web-hosted-photo-to-facebook-album-via-graph-api)

I know that you can use this code to upload to a users album

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(  
  'appId'  => 'ID',  
  'secret' => 'SECRET',  
  'fileUpload' => true,  
  'cookie' => true // enable optional cookie support  
));  


$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);  

# File is relative to the PHP doc  
$file = "@".realpath("../../_images/stuff/greatness.jpg");  

$args = array(  
    'message' => 'Photo Caption',  
    "access_token" => "urtoken",  
    "image" => $file  
);  


$data = $facebook->api('/ALBUMID_GOES_HERE/photos', 'post', $args);
if ($data) print_r("success");
```

Now this always uploads from my server, is it somehow possible that facebook takes an image from an external URL like http://www.test.com/image.jpg instead of uploading it with my server?

Comment: yes but this is old and has no real solution, his solution is to temporairly host the files on my server but I want to avoid that.

Comment: there ist no alternativ to this way, at this time.