# VB.NET Upload Photos to Facebook using Graph API

Tags: vb.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Looking for some code to upload a photo to facebook using the Graph API in VB.NET. I have the Facebook C# SDK, but it doesn't support uploading photos as far as I can tell.

Accessing the photos works fine and I can send other content to Facebook fine as well. Just not photos.

The facebook documentation talks about attaching the file as a form-multipart request, but I have no idea how to do that. To say that its not very well documented is to put it lightly. Even the guys I hire to do this kind of thing couldn't get it to work.

I've found this: [Upload Photo To Album with Facebook's Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718610/upload-photo-to-album-with-facebooks-graph-api), but it only describes how to do it in PHP.

I've also seen varying method from different sites about passing the URL of the photo as a part of the HTTP request, but after trying local or remote URLs several times I kept getting a bad url error or something like that.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the Image in a POST request to the Graph API (Need publish_stream permission). What is mentioned in Facebook Documentation is correct. Following is the example code that may do the work. use it inside a method. (Code is in C#)

**Legend**
`<content>` : you need to provide the info.

**Update**
Please post comments to improve the code.

```
string ImageData;
string queryString = string.Concat("access_token=", /*<Place your access token here>*/);
string boundary = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

StringBuilder sb = String.Empty;
sb.Append("----------").Append(boundary).Append("\r\n");
sb.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"").Append(/*<Enter you image's flename>*/).Append("\"").Append("\r\n");
sb.Append("Content-Type: ").Append(String.Format("Image/{0}"/*<Enter your file type like jpg, bmp, gif, etc>*/)).Append("\r\n").Append("\r\n");

using (FileInfo file = new FileInfo("/*<Enter the full physical path of the Image file>*/"))
{
    ImageData = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
}
byte[] postHeaderBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
byte[] fileData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ImageData);
byte[] boundaryBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Concat("\r\n", "----------", boundary, "----------", "\r\n"));
var postdata = new byte[postHeaderBytes.Length + fileData.Length + boundaryBytes.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(postHeaderBytes, 0, postData, 0, postHeaderBytes.Length);
Buffer.BlockCopy(fileData, 0, postData, postHeaderBytes.Length, fileData.Length);
Buffer.BlockCopy(boundaryBytes, 0, postData, postHeaderBytes.Length + fileData.Length, boundaryBytes.Length);

var requestUri = new UriBuilder("https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos");
requestUri.Query = queryString;
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUri.Uri);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = String.Concat("multipart/form-data; boundary=", boundary);
request.ContentLength = postData.Length;

using (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
      dataStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
}

request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: I finally got around to trying this out but I got the same "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." that i've gotten with the other methods. I noticed that you declared the request variable twice, vb.net didn't like that.

Comment: oh yeah sorry i just edited that.. and for your problem... are you sure u are using a valid access token (with publish stream Extended permission).. because that error normally returned when u dont have a valid access token.  Try using that uri with access token in a browser (GET)  request do u still get an error...