# Uploading Photos to Facebook using Graph API

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, uploading

I would like to provide users of my application with ability to upload photos to their Facebook account. The application has a username and password form for the users to fill.

In Graph API, there's a method for uploading photos. But I'm unsure how to authenticate - it doesn't seem to provide a way to supply username and password. It requires `access_token`.

What's the right way to allow users authenticating and uploading photos using username and password?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell how you want to do this without a sample code or even stating what technology you are using..
Anyway, almost ***ALL*** interactions with facebook graph api require an access token and most likely an [extended permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions).

First of all, for you to post/upload a photo you need:

1. The `publish_stream` extended permission
2. A better understanding of how and ***where*** the photo will be uploaded to, this can be done by reading the *publishing* section in the [photo documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)
3. Now that you have a general idea, in your destination/submission page of your form and when the image is successfully uploaded to your server and it's location is known (obviously), use one of the two answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718610/upload-photo-to-album-with-facebooks-graph-api) to upload the image.

P.S: I don't really understand why you need a username & password in first place, but it's your application...

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, the access_token is what you receive after the user authorize your application. So , the provision of username and password only need to be done once, when user first access your app. 
You need to redirect user browser or client to :  https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth... (Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ )

Then after you have the access_token, you can just use that for the api call to upload photo to that user.

The authorization process need to be done again when the token is expired.