# Uploading and Sharing a Photo

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, titanium

I would like to upload to an album and share the uploaded photo via the FB sharing mechanism on my and/or friends' walls.

I'm using [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) to develop my app, but I'm also happy with an Objective C example since the procedure is pretty much the same.

I achieved the upload of the photo to my album, but I can't find anything about sharing, neither in the official documentation, nor elsewhere on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using 1.6 or higher then the Titanium FB module is built to use OG and you can follow the instructions in this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718610/upload-photo-to-album-with-facebooks-graph-api).

Comment: Yes, uploading is not the problem. There is an example in the official [Titanium documentation](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Facebook-module) but I want to "share" the image after I've uploaded it. - Like the button Share on the photo's page.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood the question. To share on FB with the graph or at least to post on the users wall you can just open a dialog like at concept at the very bottom of this page. http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Facebook-module and check out the official FB documentation as well. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ Hope I'm getting the question better now and this helps :-)

Comment: Yes, I also know about the feed dialog but afaik its only capable to show external pictures via the picture attribute. But I want to advertise (aka share) one or more (freshly uploaded) album photos. Please correct me if I'm wrong but I haven't found any call to post a album's photo to a wall (mine or one of my friends').

Comment: To the best of my knowledge you can't post a photo to a wall using graph but you can put one in an album and then tag it so it would show up on a friends or your wall. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/ You need the `x` and `y` coordinates along with `publish_stream` permissions which seems like a lot of work to me :-(