# Publish photo to users Facebook album - Django/Python

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to publish a photo available on the server to a users Photo album. Is this a job for Python/Django or can it be done through Javascript?

And does anyone have any example code.
I've been going round in circles on this for a week ...

I've got the users access_token and permissions to publish.

**Update**:
Basically, something like the below, but in Django/Python. So I can call on a page upload a photo from the server and, post to the users wall.

[Upload Photo To Album with Facebook's Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718610/upload-photo-to-album-with-facebooks-graph-api)

Thanks again,

Comment: this question is very vague. this can be done using server side script (i.e. django, etc) or from the client using javascript. it depends on your application's architecture. I would take a look at the facebook API for sample code.

Comment: Thanks @akonsu, I've updated the question a bit more. Hope it makes more sense.

Comment: It seems like there isn't any built-in photo upload support in the Python SDK - but there is a discussion and workaround here: http://www.vibesphere.com/2011/07/file-uploads-hack-for-facebook-python-sdk/