# Uploading image to Facebook by using Curl PHP

Tags: php, image, facebook, curl, upload

I read the instructions: [Upload Photo To Album with Facebook's Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718610/upload-photo-to-album-with-facebooks-graph-api/7306889#7306889)

But although I follow the instructions, the image can't be uploaded to FB. Here is my code. Please help me.

```
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/". $album_id . "/photos?access_token=" . $access_token;

$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url );

$post_array = array(
        "source" =>"@". realpath("photo.jpg"),
        "message"=>"Upload " . date('Y-m-d h:i:s') 
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array); 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/". $album_id . "/photos?access_token=" . $access_token;

$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url );

$post_array = array(
        "source" =>"@". realpath("photo.jpg"),
        "message"=>"Upload " . date('Y-m-d h:i:s') 
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array); 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: "image can't be uploaded to FB". Why not? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Did you manage to do it?

Comment: Should `$post_url` be replaced with `$graph_url`? It's also not clear why you duplicate the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and see the result:

```
echo realpath("photo.jpg")
```

Does it return you the correct path?

Try with `/photo.jpg` or `./photo`

Comment: I'm trying same method to post image to fb. I checked path coming from realpath and it's correct, but still curl returns empty string. any idea?