# Facebook C# SDK - How to post to user's timeline with a 400x210 link image?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I got a code which successfully posts to the user's timeline on facebook using the facebook c# sdk. My problem is that I have to post a 400x210 image. The code I have does work but, even If the image filled in the picture argument is a 400x210 dimension image, It appears small and cut at the user's timeline.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient("xxxxxxx");
    var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    args["message"] = "message text";
    args["caption"] = "caption";
    args["description"] = "message";
    args["name"] = "name";
    args["picture"] = "picture of the 400x210 image";
    args["link"] = "link url";
    client.Post("me/feed/", args);
```

I've been searching the facebook api docs, here (stackoverflow), and google but I didn't find the answer for this.

Would anyone know what I have to change in my code to make the imagem appear in its full size at the user's timeline?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you want to upload the photo to Facebook through the graph api, instead of creating a wall post.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3006867/1783240) for a php example, and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/) for the Facebook HowTo